# Csv file is empty when I writing content

Tags: java, spring

I am trying write to a csv file. After the execution of the code bellow the csv file is still empty.
File is in folder `.../webapp/resources/`.

This is my dao class:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

private Resource cvsFile;

public void setCvsFile(Resource cvsFile) {
    this.cvsFile = cvsFile;
}

@Override
public void createUser(User user) {

    String userPropertiesAsString = user.getId() + "," + user.getName()
            + "," + user.getSurname() +"\n";;

    System.out.println(cvsFile.getFilename());

    FileWriter outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileWriter(cvsFile.getFile());
        outputStream.append(userPropertiesAsString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public List<User> getAll() {
    return null;
}
}
```

This is a part of `beans.xml`.

```
<bean id="userDao" class="pl.project.dao.UserDaoImpl"
    p:cvsFile="/resources/users.cvs"/>
```

Program compiles and doesn't throw any exceptions but CSV file is empty.

Comment: The reason why its empty is due to the fact that you do not close the stream. 
Additionally as @fge wrote above, use try-with-resources approach to avoid need to manually close the streHam.
Reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're running your app in IDE, the `/webapp/resources` used for running app will differ from the `/webapp/resources` in your IDE. Try to log full path to file and check there.

Answer (score 1):

try using `outputStream.flush()` as the final statement in the first of the try block.

Comment: `close()` automatically flushes the data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SVMRAJESH This looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Need more explanation instead of single line comment. Then only it will be useful for further referrers also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at the wrong file. If you specify an absolute path `/resources/users.cvs`, then it probably won't be written into the a folder relative to the webapp. Instead, it will be written to `/resources/users.cvs`

So the first step is to always log an absolute path to make sure the file is where you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, it will at least tell you where the problem lies (Java 7+):

```
// Why doesn't this method throw an IOException?
@Override
public void createUser(final User user)
{
    final String s = String.format("%s,%s,%s",
        Objects.requireNonNull(user).getId(),
        user.getName(), user.getSurname()
    );

    // Note: supposes that .getFile() returns a File object
    final Path path = csvFile.getFile().toPath().toAbsolutePath();

    final Path csv;

    // Note: this supposes that the CSV is supposed to exist!
    try {
        csv = path.toRealPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot locate CSV " + path, e);
    }

    try (
        // Note: default is to TRUNCATE the destination.
        // If you want to append, add StandardOpenOption.APPEND.
        // See javadoc for more details.
        final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(csv,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ) {
        writer.write(s);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("write failure", e);
    }
}
```